# R session aborted, encountered a fatal error when combining large rds files

Tags: r

I want to combine 3 large RDS files (two of them are around 100 MB and one is around 270MB) into one. Each time I run the code, my R Session aborts and I get the error message that R encountered a fatal error.

I already tried to clear my global environment and updated all the packages, but it didn't help.

I have a 2 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 processor and 8 GB 1867 MHz LPDDR3.

My session info:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default

LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:

[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

 [1] compiler_4.0.3     magrittr_2.0.1     Matrix_1.3-4       tools_4.0.3        fastmatch_1.1-3    Rcpp_1.0.7        
 [7] tinytex_0.34       stringi_1.7.5      grid_4.0.3         quanteda_3.1.0     xfun_0.27          stopwords_2.3     
[13] RcppParallel_5.1.4 lattice_0.20-45
```

The code I want to run:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)

rds_alle_tweets <- (list.files(pattern = "*.rds", full.names = TRUE))
  map_dfr(
    .x = rds_alle_tweets,
    .f = ~read_rds(.x) %>% mutate_all(as.character))
```

Did someone encounter a similar problem or has a fix for it?

I posted the same question already in the Rstudio community, but so far no one could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am guessing you are hitting memory limits. Load rds one by one, cleanup, keep only necessary columns, output to a file, then read the files in.